# WordPress functions.php syntax

Tags: php, function, wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin

Looking to modify my child `functions.php` file to include some logic that ties together Gravity Forms and Ulitmate Member plugins. In that when a user comes to my site and fill out a form I need to capture a hidden field thats dynamically populated with their ultimate member role. I attempted to add the below into my `functions.php` file but it just ended up rendering my site with all blank pages.

```
add_filter('gform_field_value_um_role', 'getUM_userrole');
function getUM_userrole($value){
$umrole = echo um_user('role_name');
    return  $umrole;
}
```

Here's the resources I was using to come up with the above:
http://docs.ultimatemember.com/article/158-umuser 
https://www.gravityhelp.com/documentation/article/using-dynamic-population/#hooks

And my hidden field settings: [image]

Comment: Assigning `echo` to a variable.?

Comment: take that out? so we'd end up with `echo um_user('role_name');
    return;` ?

Comment: No, you should never assign `echo` to a variable. Meaning `$umrole = echo um_user('role_name');` should be `$umrole = um_user('role_name');`. This may or may not solve the actual problem...but it'll at least make you one step closer.

Comment: try turning on `wp_debug`, might show you something useful.  It happened to me once and turned out to be some extra whitespace at the end of the file

Comment: updated it to `add_filter('gform_field_value_um_role', 'getUM_userrole');
function getUM_userrole($value){
$umrole = um_user('role_name');
    return  $umrole;
}` and the page at least loads now but my hidden field isn't populated. 

will try wp debug next

Comment: We'll I haven't had much luck here - I realized that I probably need to declare a couple of variables as global in my functions file so this is what it currently looks like, page load, form gets submitted yet I still do not have that hidden field populated.

`global $ultimatemember;
global $user_ID;

add_filter('gform_field_value_um_role', 'getUM_userrole');
function getUM_userrole($value){
um_fetch_user( $user_ID ); // set user id to retrieve
return var_dump( $ultimatemember->user->get_role() ); // get user's roles. }`

Answer (score 0):

Tony,

I've had problems dynamically setting Gravity form values before especially in the naming convention for the filter name. However, if you use the filter *gform_field_value* as in my example below you should be able to pre-populate your field name correctly. All I'm doing here is just checking if it's the correct field and then setting and returning the value parameter. Hopefully this will help you out

```
add_filter( 'gform_field_value', 'getUM_userrole', 10, 3 );
function getUM_userrole($value, $field){
    if($field->inputName=="um_role")
    {
        $value = um_user('role_name');
        return $value;
    }
    return false;
}
```